# Aligning axes of different sizes within a GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, alignment, axes

I have a trivial question but not able find a effective solution. I hope somebody could help me in this regard.

I currently have 4 different axes in a GUI. ax1(top left) and ax4(bottom left) should be aligned vertically and similarly ax2(top right) and ax4(bottom right) should be aligned vertically. (I have attached a sample image)

ax1 and ax2 are used to show images that are usually larger in size(~512x512) and ax3 & ax4 are used to display images of size ~43x512. Even though I created the axes with x-axis the same size when I display images they change size and not aligned anymore. No matter what images I display, I want the top and bottom images to of same x length and aligned always.

I tried to keep the XLim the same; XData the same but still doesnt work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Bala

Comment: 1) There is no image attached and 2) Are you using GUIDE to build your GUI?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here, we solve errors in code in a Q&A format. Please post some code that you have written and an image illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [align](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/align.html) function which is used to do just that. The calling syntax is as follows:

```
align(HandleList,'HorizontalAlignment','VerticalAlignment')
```

Therefore in you case, you could write something like this (Note that you wrote ax4 twice in your question, I guess you wish to align axes 1-3 and 2-4):

```
align([handles.ax1 handles.ax3],'VerticalAlignment','none', 'HorizontalAlignment','center')
```

and likewise for the other 2 axes:

```
align([handles.ax2 handles.ax4],'VerticalAlignment','none', 'HorizontalAlignment','center')
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Looks like my issue might not be just alignment. I tried aligning them but when the size of ax1 changes (for e.g. from 512x512 to say 150 x 250, the size of the image in ax2 will be 43 x 250) and hence I want them to change proportionally and still be aligned.
Do you think I need to change some properties to indicate they change proportionally OR ax2 to follow ax1 whenever the size changes? Maybe use 'Position' property?

Comment: Mhh I guess you could use the `linkprop` function to link the axes' position property. Info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkprop.html). Please tell me if this does not work!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But linkprop didnt solve the issue completely. Looks like I need something to resize to match the axes above. I think what I found is, if the size of the image is different from the axes size, the image resizes automatically and hence not the same size as axes when displayed. So I guess I need something(a command or property) that will fill the axes when displayed.

thanks!